How to correctly say that I “changed my mind” and do it beautifully?
Not long ago, a company contacted me and offered me a job with them, since they were very interested in my candidacy.  Communication proceeded easily, without breakdowns or other conflicts, everything was very smooth.  Thus, I constantly maintained contact with HR and through him with the boss.  Unfortunately, despite the very favorable atmosphere of communication, something was still hidden from me until the last.
Let's put it this way: the company does not have a very transparent management and motivation system, a complex and confusing system of information exchange between departments within the company and with other companies, plus during especially busy periods of work on projects there is overtime.  The fact is that the company has taken and is taking part in defense projects.
The manager with whom I talked told me all this, shared a brochure of regulations about the company’s work, offered to study it and gave me time to think - a day.  Unfortunately, this turned out to be too little to understand everything, and I hastened to answer, refusing the offer, citing the fact that such a working mode does not suit the rhythm of my life and does not meet my interests and internal needs.
They told me that the proposed conditions were an integral part of their work, but they asked me to have the opportunity to further interact with me if they had tasks that matched my interests and requests.  I agreed and also noted that if such tasks arise, I am ready to completely switch to working for them, without part-time employment elsewhere.
Now I really regret that I refused them, because...  looked at the proposal from a different angle, as opportunities and new prospects.  They have a lot of interesting projects, for which they even tried to adapt me.  Of course, these are not some secret developments, but that is not the point.
After thinking about it a little more and studying the documents more carefully, I realized that the system there is complex, but well-functioning and you can completely understand it, because  Despite its complexity, it provides space for full-fledged activity for the result.  And I change my mind.
My question: How to say that I “change my mind” correctly?  I want to write them a new message and express my agreement to work for them.  But how to do it correctly and beautifully, so that you don’t get a negative impression and, on the contrary, get a profit (or at least a zero). I had doubts whether it was worth getting involved with these topics, and I referred to worldview requests. But after I think - why not? I realized that work would not disrupt anything in my life.  I just needed a little more time to think.

Simply say "Sorry, but I change my mind". As you can see, it is not that difficult. Business is business. Companies do what is in their best interest. You should do what works best for you.

The idea of beauty, in this context, probably differs from person to person within the organisation you're writing to, and none of them may correspond to your idea of beauty.

Assume that any job you declined was immediately taken by the next candidate.
You made your decision. Learn whatever lessons you can learn from it and move on to the next application.

What if the job is quite unique both for the industry and for the city, but a candidate has not yet been found?

There is no elegant way to say "oops". Settle for inelegant. "If the opening still exists, I think I would like to be considered for it after all " It might help to give them a good explanation of what misunderstanding caused you to drop out before, but no matter what you do this is going to read as "I couldn't get my first choice and I don't have a lot of other offers so I'm reluctantly asking to be considered again", which is not a great look. Hope they take pity on you, but don't expect it; continue interviewing elsewhere.

I'll just make a small clarification.  We went through a series of interviews and they already invited me directly to go out and work.  And they waited for my decision.  But I refused.  There are big disadvantages (for an employee if he cannot adapt) in their organization, and they are well aware of them.

That's just silly advice. There is absolute no harm in reaching out and asking again. If they say "no", you can still move on. If they say "yes" you have new job. Why not try?
